# Extract value in the data layer variable in Google Tag Manger

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I am now writing a cookie for the browser in google tag manager, so as to calculate the page score. But I have a problem that the gtm.timer ran a couple of times, and the score just being added for multiple times, when the timer keep triggering.

[image]

And now I come up with a idea, that I can use the datalayer variable as a condition (i.e if the timerEventNumber is greater then 1 then do not return new value). 
[image]

However, the problem is, how can I reference the value of the data layer variable from a custom javascript?

Many thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply define your Data Layer type variable as `gtm.timerEventNumber` and use that in your Custom JS variable, eg. if you've named your variable as "DL - gtm.timerEventNumber":

```
function(){
   if ({{DL - gtm.timerEventNumber}} > 1){
      // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: I finally defined another custom variable to use the value. But still, thanks you for your help!